# Local RDLC tablix get expand from second page

Tags: winforms, reporting-services, rdlc, report-viewer2010, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am using Rdlc report in windows application. rdlc report is working perfect but the only problem with the design.
when running the report in reportviewer design is constant on first page but from second page TABLIX get expand around 1" Right and Top.

Properties I have applied:

```
ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace   = true 
canSrink  =False  
CanGrow = False;
```

but this still gives the same issues.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issues.
need to use **List** Control instead of **Table/Tablix** Control in details report.

Thanks a lot